# ¿Cómo puedo contar la cantidad de registros en t1 que coincida con id de t2 y si no existe me muestre 0?

Tags: sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas en SQL Server 2008:

**Tabla Estado:**

```
ID, NombreEstado
```

**Tabla equipo:**

```
ID, id_estado, NombreEquipo
```

Necesito saber la cantidad de equipos(tabla equipo) para cada uno de los estados(tabla estado). Esto es fácil, pero no he logrado que sí no existen registros con alguno de los estados, me muestre 0.
Ej:

```
estado 1 = 10 equipos
estado 2 = 3 equipos
estado 3 = 0 equipos
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT es.nombreestado , SUM(CASE WHEN es.id = eq.id_estado THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) equipos 
FROM estado es LEFT JOIN equipo eq ON es.id = eq.id_estado
GROUP BY es.nombreestado;
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que estamos haciendo es declarar dentro de la funcion SUM el CASE para que cuando encuentre una conincidencia de estados la sume y de no encontrar registro le coloque un 0, al final agrupamos por nombre de estados y listo,  espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: La respuesta es buena, pero esta: `FROM estado es ,equipo eq` no debería ser la forma de hacer un *join* entre las tablas sino explícitamente usar un `join/left join`

Answer (score 0):

Hola es con `LEFT JOIN` que se utiliza para seleccionar todos los campos de la tabla de la izquiera, y con `ISNULL` para que cuando sea `null` muestre 0.

```
SELECT e.ID, e.NombreEquipo, ISNULL(s.ID, 0) IDEstado
FROM   tbEquipo e
       LEFT JOIN tbEstado s
           ON e.id_estado = s.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
select
    count(*) cantidad
from
    estado e
    join equipo eq
        on e.id=eq.estado
group by eq.estado
```